# Find fewest number of letters to get the final value

Tags: python

I have a letters which each one has weight like A to E also i know the finalvalue which is 8. Basically i need to find the combination ( + ) of letters which will add up to finalvalue with least count of letters.
    ( Ex: 8 can be (A+E) or (A+B+C) but result should be A+E as we used just 2 letters)

```
A = 1
B = A*2+ 1
C = 4
D = 1
E =  B*1 + 4
finalvalue = 8

minimum = float("inf")
dict1 = {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C": 4, "D": 1, "E": 7 }
value_chosen = 8
string1 = ""
for i, j in dict1.items():
    if abs(j - value_chosen) < minimum:
        final_value = j
        minimum = abs(j - value_chosen)

print(final_value)

# Here i am getting value 7 , then reading that to string

x = (list(dict1.keys())[list(dict1.values()).index(final_value)])
string1 = string1 + x
print(string1)
```

then try to delete that and iterate over the rest to match the finalvalue but no success..  Can someone please help me here how to finish up this code with out  complex algorithams ( As i am begineer )

Comment: This looks like a change giving problem

Comment: Hi Masque.. sorry didn't get it. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe this can help - [Coin Change Maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317241/coin-change-maker-python-program)